# Import .htaccess rules in IIS using command line

Tags: iis, mod-rewrite, iis-7, iis-7.5

Is it possible to import/convert a `mod_rewrite` .htaccess file to `web.config` using the command line (NOT using GUI as [described here](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/470/importing-apache-modrewrite-rules/)) and how ?

If it is not directly possible is there any workaround for this ?

Comment: The tags suggest that you mean `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` directives only, but neither the title nor the question body make it clear. Perhaps that's why there aren't any answers so far. You also suggest you found a GUI tool; could you give further details about it?

Comment: Hi , I have added the information.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't possible to do this from the command line. The importer code is part of the UrlRewrite extension code and only surfaced via the IIS manager UI.

That said, if you have .NET Reflector (or a similar tool - [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ilspy.ashx)) you can inspect the code that performs the `mod_rewrite` translation.

From my own investigations, the UrlRewrite extension lives inside the following assemblies:

```
Microsoft.Web.Management.Rewrite  
Microsoft.Web.Management.Rewrite.Client
```

These reside in the GAC and can be opened quite easily for inspection by .NET Reflector.

The classes and methods of interest are:

`Microsoft.Web.Management.Iis.Rewrite.Translation.ImportRulesPage.Translate()`

which calls:

`Microsoft.Web.Management.Iis.Rewrite.Translation.Translator.Translate()`

From this information it may be possible to reverse engineer your own command line implementation.